# JavaScript: Guess data type from string

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a function that can tell me to which data type a string might be converted.
Examples:

"28.98" results in float (. as separator)

"44.332,95" results in float (, as separator)

"29/04/14" results in date (should work internationally -> different date formats)

"34.524" results in int (. as delimited)

"all the rest" results in string

Ideally also (these are subclasses of string):

"something@example.com" results in e-mail

"+49/2234/234567" results in phone

Is there a (open source) libary can can do such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you parse something like that: 1,2,3,444.555.666,777,888,+92/12/12/12/12/12/12.12?

Comment: Since this does not match anything else, it would be a string.

Comment: Why it doesn't match anything else? You mean, the whole string should match some type, or tokens should be separated by whitespace? Your requirements exclude using commas or slashes as separators...

Comment: Yes, I always consider the whole string as one element. And no, I don't want to limit the imput / exclude some characters.

Comment: OK, but with dates you generally can't. 01/02/03 could be 1st Feb 2003 or 3rd Feb 2001, but Americans could see 2nd Jan 2003 or 2nd Mar 2001 (they are often using middle-indian for dates)

Comment: Number formats and date formats are widely varied across different cultures. Consider implementing the cultures you want explicitly, if that 's possible. Also, specialized strings like email and telephone strings can be very difficult to properly support, so try supporting only the things you need.

Comment: Ofcourse you can, but you will have to implement a formating string for all the ISO number formats used. In Smart Pascal that compiles to JS I implemented this and it was "not fun", but ported over fine from Delphi and freepascal. The same in raw JS is more than doable as an associative array and then checking the navigator object i seem to remember -- but yeah, you will need to do some classic hard parsing if you want to make it rock solid. Or some monstrocity regular expression soup

Answer (score 6):

There you have it. Not a library, unhealthy amount of regular expressions, but it works with your examples. If you need other things to be matched, please add more examples. Open to critique or requirements in the comments.

```
function getType(str){
    if (typeof str !== 'string') str = str.toString();
    var nan = isNaN(Number(str));
    var isfloat = /^\d*(\.|,)\d*$/;
    var commaFloat = /^(\d{0,3}(,)?)+\.\d*$/;
    var dotFloat = /^(\d{0,3}(\.)?)+,\d*$/;
    var date = /^\d{0,4}(\.|\/)\d{0,4}(\.|\/)\d{0,4}$/;
    var email = /^[A-za-z0-9._-]*@[A-za-z0-9_-]*\.[A-Za-z0-9.]*$/;
    var phone = /^\+\d{2}\/\d{4}\/\d{6}$/g;
    if (!nan){
        if (parseFloat(str) === parseInt(str)) return "integer";
        else return "float";
    }
    else if (isfloat.test(str) || commaFloat.test(str) || dotFloat.test(str)) return "float";
    else if (date.test(str)) return "date";
    else {
        if (email.test(str)) return "e-mail";
        else if (phone.test(str)) return "phone";
        else return "string";
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case just lazy evaluate everything. here you test every regex but in most case won't use more than half of it.

Comment: So let's create a library

Answer (score -2):

Has been a while since I worked with JavaScript frameworks, but what you are working on is rather simple. You can do it yourself, by checking if the logical differences exist in your string, the way you are presenting them here. For example, you can use the `indexOf()` JavaScript function to check if an @ sign exists in your string. If you have both a dot and a comma, means that you get a floating point number. Lastly, the difference you want between 28.98 and 34.524 cannot be presented in any way, since the `.` is always a floating point mark for numbers, meaning that 34.524 is a float for both human and computer.

Hope it helps - probably not with the library you were asking for though!

[`indexOf()` function in w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp)

Comment: I am aware that it should not be too hard to implement this by myself - but in order to cover (nearly) all cases (esp. for the date), it seems like a lot of work.
By the way: the . is not always a float point mark; in Germany for example the , would be used for that.

Comment: You didn't mention that you want multilingual and localisation services. And what you do in Germany is a left-over from the Greek's manipulation on the arabic number representation! The international usage goes with dot as a decimal sign and comma for thousand separation.